# Parse argument to JSON string in python

Tags: python, json

I want to do following in my python script:

```
d = {"dpid": + sys.argv [1] + ,"flow_id" : "flow0001"," "actions":{"output":2}}
```

Its a JSON string further I am loading in my application, can any help, how should I parse that argument in the string ?

Comment: Your JSON structure is not correct. Please fix it and what is the expected output?

Comment: *how should I parse that argument in the string ?* you mean the `sys.argv[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is incorrect. Replace it with:

```
d  = "{\"dpid\":" + sys.argv[1] + ",\"flow_id\":\"flow0001\",\"actions\":{\"output\":2}}"
```

Make sure the argument you type is an integer. If you want to parse the json string and get the dpid later, write this (python 3 code):

```
import json
j = json.loads(d)
print(j['dpid'])
```

Comment: Why not use `json.dumps(d)` instead of manually constructing the JSON?

Comment: @TimCastelijns I never knew that! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If your file name is test.py 
Then
pass args like below

```
$ python test.py arg1 arg2 arg3
```

in test.py file you can access them as string by str(sys.argv[index])

in your scenario

```
d = '{"dpid":"' + str(sys.argv [1]) +'" ,"flow_id":"flow0001", "actions":{"output":2}}'
```

then parse that string as below,

```
import json
obj = json.loads(d)
```

Comment: if we have correct format of string representation then no need of dumps.  in above scenario'  d ' holds a string representation of json object it will give object when we use loads function  .   just check it out @TimCastelijns